# Docusign .net send enevlope issue on one server

Tags: docusignapi

We've implement docusign api into our application and it works fine in development and on one of our production servers, but on particular production server it fails when running the following line

var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel);

The exception thrown is

Error: InvalidDataContractException: Message: Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[DocuSign.DocuSignWeb.SetSharedAccessResult]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Here is the complete method that is called

```
    public DocuSignResponse SendEnvelope(Envelope envelope, string templateGUID)
    {
        var response = new DocuSignResponse();

        var client = new DSAPIServiceSoapClient("DSAPIServiceSoap", URL);
        try
        {
            var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel);
            {
                HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", AuthHeader);
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

                if (client.InnerChannel.State != System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    // call service - everything's fine
                }
                else
                {
                    // channel faulted - re-create your client and then try again
                    response.Success = false;
                    response.ErrorMessage = "Channel has faulted!!";
                    return response;
                }

                client.Open();

                EnvelopeStatus envelopeStatus;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateGUID))
                {
                    DocuSignWeb.EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new DocuSignWeb.EnvelopeInformation();
                    envelopeInfo.AccountId = AccountId;
                    envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = envelope.EmailBlurb;
                    envelopeInfo.Subject = envelope.Subject;

                    // Configure the inline templates
                    DocuSignWeb.InlineTemplate inlineTemplate = new DocuSignWeb.InlineTemplate();
                    inlineTemplate.Sequence = "1";
                    inlineTemplate.Envelope = new DocuSignWeb.Envelope();
                    inlineTemplate.Envelope.Recipients = envelope.Recipients;
                    inlineTemplate.Envelope.AccountId = AccountId;

                    DocuSignWeb.CompositeTemplate template = new DocuSignWeb.CompositeTemplate();
                    template.InlineTemplates = new DocuSignWeb.InlineTemplate[] {inlineTemplate};

                    DocuSignWeb.ServerTemplate serverTemplate = new DocuSignWeb.ServerTemplate();
                    serverTemplate.Sequence = "1";
                    serverTemplate.TemplateID = templateGUID;

                    template.ServerTemplates = new[] {serverTemplate};
                    template.Document = envelope.Documents[0];

                    envelopeStatus = client.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms(envelopeInfo, new[] {template}, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    envelopeStatus = client.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
                }

                // An envelope ID indicates that it succeeded
                response.Success = true;
                response.ResponseRef = envelopeStatus.EnvelopeID;

                // No point doing this, as it wouldn't have been signed
                // Request the status of that envelope                        
                // response.Status = client.RequestStatus(envelopeStatus.EnvelopeID);

                // Used if embed option being used
                response.Envelope = envelope;
                response.Status = envelopeStatus;


                if (client.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    client.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    client.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidDataContractException err)
        {               
            err.LogError();

            response.Success = false;

            response.ErrorMessage = string.Format("InvalidDataContractException: Message: {0} StackTrace: {1} AuthHeader: {2}", err.Message, err.StackTrace, AuthHeader);
        }
        catch (CommunicationException err)
        {
            err.LogError();                
            response.Success = false;
            response.ErrorMessage = string.Format("CommunicationException: Message: {0} StackTrace: {1}", err.Message, err.StackTrace);

            client.Abort();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException err)
        {
             err.LogError();

            response.Success = false;
            response.ErrorMessage = string.Format("TimeoutException: Message: {0} StackTrace: {1}", err.Message, err.StackTrace);

            client.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
             err.LogError();

            response.Success = false;
            response.ErrorMessage = string.Format("Exception: Message: {0} StackTrace: {1}", err.Message, err.StackTrace);

            client.Abort();                
        }
        finally
        {
            client = null;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

At the moment i'm at a loss as to what the issue is, given the same code and database works on another  machines, so at present thinking it's environmental.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Going from the error message, sounds like a node in the message can't be serialized. I'd look carefully at all of the values in the message that's causing the error. Any fields with weird values? Initialized but unset sub-objects? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for that. The trouble is the error happens on the call for the OperationContextScope which has very little code set before. If it was an code initialisation issue I would expect that issue to occur locally and on the other server that does work.

Comment: Well I've just tried the same code, and it's now working, so no idea why it was failing but now is working. It does seem the server has just installed some windows updates so may be to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this turned out to be server issues on DocuSign side.  Occasionally there are bugs and other issues that get rolled back in DocuSign's Demo sandbox environment.