# DocuSign API and DocumentPDFs docPDFs = apiService.RequestDocumentPDFs(envelopeID);

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using the code below to connect to DocuSign API.
WHAT AM I doing wrong, I keep getting Username and Password not correct when they are!

```
String auth = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>john.connolly@lechase.com</Username><Password>password</Password><IntegratorKey>20be051c-4c25-46c1-b0f1-1f10575a2e40</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

DSAPIServiceSoapClient client = new DSAPIServiceSoapClient("DSAPIServiceSoap");
using (System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope scope = new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", auth);
    System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

    EnvelopeStatus status = client.RequestStatusEx("12d46951-1f1c-48cd-9a28-e51685d67ccd");
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Subject: " + status.Subject);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use the ([Legacy Header Authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html) uses the X-DocuSign-Authentication header):

> 1. Use the [Authentication: login method](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/login/)
>      to retrieve the account number **and the baseUrl** for the account.
>      The url for the login method is www.docusign.net for production and
>      demo.docusign.net for the developer sandbox. The `baseUrl` field is
>      part of the `loginAccount` object. See the [docs and the loginAccount
>      object](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/login/#/definitions/loginAccount)
> 2. The baseUrl for the selected account, in production, will start with na1, na2, na3, eu1, or something else. Use the baseUrl that is
>      returned to create the *basePath* (see the next step.) Use the
>      basePath for all of your subsequent API calls.
> 3. As returned by login method, the baseUrl includes the API version and account id. Split the string to obtain the *basePath*, just the
>      server name and api name. Eg, you will receive
>      `https://na1.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/123123123`. You want
>      just `https://na1.docusign.net/restapi`
> 4. Instantiate the SDK using the basePath. Eg `ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);`
> 5. Set the authentication header as shown in the examples by using `Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader` [Ref](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/README.md).

Sample Code: Try a verbatim string for your auth string.

```
string auth = @"<DocuSignCredentials>
                   <Username>john.connolly@lechase.com</Username>
                   <Password>S3cre+p455w0Rd</Password>
                   <IntegratorKey>20be051c-4c25-46c1-b0f1-1f10575a2e40</IntegratorKey>
                </DocuSignCredentials>";

DSAPIServiceSoapClient apiService = new DSAPIServiceSoapClient();            

using (var scope = new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(apiService.InnerChannel))
{
    var httpRequestProperty = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", auth);
    System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

    EnvelopeStatus envStatus = apiService.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
    return envStatus.EnvelopeID;
}
```

Comment: I am a little lost can you give me the code for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051550/docusign-net-send-enevlope-issue-on-one-server